# Borland C++ - Boost Library 1.55 Error

Tags: c++, boost, borland-c++

OS: Windows 7
IDE: Borland Builder 6

I tried to add the mysql connector, and appeared such errors. How to fix it?

```
  [C++ Error] substitute_fwd.hpp(49): E2401 Invalid template argument list
  [C++ Error] substitute_fwd.hpp(49): E2041 Incorrect use of default
  [C++ Error] substitute_fwd.hpp(49): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly
  [C++ Error] meta_utils.hpp(54): E2401 Invalid template argument list
  [C++ Error] meta_utils.hpp(54): E2303 Type name expected
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(38): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(46): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(54): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(68): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(69): E2034 Cannot convert 'move_detail::is_rv<T>::value' to 'bool'
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(70): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(76): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(77): E2034 Cannot convert 'move_detail::is_rv<T>::value' to 'bool'
  [C++ Error] utility.hpp(78): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] iterator.hpp(43): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] algorithm.hpp(177): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] algorithm.hpp(216): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] algorithm.hpp(240): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] algorithm.hpp(263): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
  [C++ Error] static_assert.hpp(62): E2221 Macro argument syntax error
  [C++ Error] static_assert.hpp(182): E2221 Macro argument syntax error
  [C++ Error] aligned_storage.hpp(51): E2272 Identifier expected
  [C++ Error] aligned_storage.hpp(56): E2321 Declaration does not specify a tag or an identifier
  [C++ Error] cstdint.hpp(380): E2272 Identifier expected
  [C++ Error] cstdint.hpp(381): E2272 Identifier expected
  [C++ Error] cstdint.hpp(381): E2228 Too many error or warning messages
```

Comment: I'm going to guess it has something to do with the fact that C++ Builder 6 is [twelve years old](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Borland_Compiler_Release_Dates).  **[This](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/Guidelines/Borland)** and **[this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/config/compiler/borland.hpp)** may provide some clues/details.  I think if you want to make trouble free use of Boost, you should use a different compiler.

Comment: Version 1.55 of boost has not been tested with Borland C++ 6.0.  Just the fact that those errors are template related would indicate that you have little to no hope in getting BC 6.0 to work with 1.55.

Comment: You can only use versions of boost that have been bundled with Borland or Embarcadero C++  (they have fixes made by Borland etc. to work around compiler failings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in most cases to make MSVC++ like libs to work in Borland/Embarcadero environment:

- reorder and/or add `#include` statements
- add missing #define

anyway for MySQL you can use their own hinterface like **libmysql.dll** instead of boost

- it work well (tested in BCB5,BDS2006)
- just get `libmysql.dll` + header files (downloadable from MySQL pages and also included in some installations)
- create Intel/Borland compatible lib file with implib.exe tool (it is in Borlands bin folder)

link it to your project + add include and that it is all

usage is almost the same as in PHP

[notes]

- I never properly tested BCB6 because it is extremly buggy
- BCB5 was way more better in everything so I switch back almost immediately
- now I use BDS2006 which is also old but can do almost anything 32bit in it and is free for 100 years
- with some minor restrictions which I don't mind anyway
- sadly Embarcadero downed its server so no new licenses can be obtained to it (at least that I know of)